# Using Webservice credentials for ObjectDataSource asp .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, authentication

I have a question:

I have webservice which requires username and password (Basic/ Windows authentication)

I have setup a web project in Visual Studio 2010 using “Add web reference” (normal stuff…right)

Here is the ASPX code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repUnserName" runat="server" DataSourceID="objGetUserName">
    <ItemTemplate>
        Name: <span class="info">
            <%# Eval("myName")%></span>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="objGetUserName" runat="server" SelectMethod="getUserNameByEmail"
    TypeName="SecureService" OnSelecting="objGetUserName_Selecting">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="" Name="UserEmail" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

c# Code:

```
protected void objGetUserName_Selecting(object sender, ObjectDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
    {            
            e.InputParameters["UserEmail"] = "myemail@email.com 

    }
```

Now my question is how can I pass webservice login credentials when calling getUserByEmail method using ObjectDataSource ?

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to have a wrapper method in the page (or in some helper class) to control credential passing. For example,

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="objGetUserName" runat="server" SelectMethod="getUserNameByEmail"
    TypeName="PageClassName" OnSelecting="objGetUserName_Selecting">

internal static DataTable getUserNameByEmail(string email)
{
    var proxy = new SecureService();
    proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredentials("user-name", "password");
    return proxy.getUserNameByEmail(email);
}
```

*Disclaimer: untested code - just to get the idea of solution*

Answer (score 0):

This is what I end up doing:

Creating "Object Creating event"

Sample Code:

```
protected void MyObjDS_ObjectCreating(object sender, ObjectDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
MyWebService.Service webProxy = new MyWebService.Service();
webProxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
e.ObjectInstance = webProxy;
}
```

Source URL: http://paulsiu.wordpress.com/2008/08/31/error-401-when-using-objectdatasource-to-call-a-web-service/#comment-4023